# Website, elements suddenly stops at 400px width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, width, mobile-website

My [page](https://unique-macaron-168d77.netlify.app). Elements suddenly stops at 400px width. When you open DevTools in responsive mode and change the size under 400px width, elements stays at this specific width and wont get smaller. My question is why? I think there is one element which "breaks" this for all other elements, but I cant debug which one (or more) it is. HTML tag from this point starts to shrink and not getting 100% of website width. This website is still in development.

HTML tag is set to:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

I tried to set a fixed width size for a few elements that I thought were causing this. Of course It didnt help...What Am I missing?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Updating the `.home-services-container` for `grid-template-columns` value to `minmax(min(100%, 300px), 1fr)` should solve your issue. The minimum value that you set there was the problem, preventing it to stop shrinking below 300px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1 element which "breaks" this for all other elements is... `div.home-services-container` inside `div.smaller-services-section`
it has

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
padding: 5em;
```

if you go to `Computed` (next to `Styles`) tab inside Chrome DevTools where you inspect elements you'll find that this `padding: 5em` tanslates to a padding of `50px` on the left and `50px` on the right. Adding this to the `300px` (from `minmax(300px, 1fr)`) we get our `400px`

Hope this helps. Good luck with development!

Comment: It worked, thank you very much...but border-box is active shouldnt margin and padding be included? Or this grid template computing is different?

Comment: @Røbin `grid-template-columns` doesn't know of any other properties so the `300px` you specified in the minmax is only the width of "inner" content (excluding paddings etc.)